# getting all rows whether it exists in the current query result or no

Tags: sql-server

first sorry for the bad title i didn't know what should i name it.

i have a table that has customers and the items they bought.
ex:

```
Customer_ID | Item_ID |
--------------------------
1           | 15      |
3           | 25      |
5           | 20      |
1           | 35      |
```

the database is for a system like auction so all the items have a history for all the previous prices.
ex:

```
Item_ID | Price | Date
--------------------------
15      | 200   | 4/11/2015
25      | 100   | 4/11/2015
20      | 250   | 4/11/2015
35      | 350   | 4/11/2015
15      | 3000  | 5/11/2015
```

what i do is that i iterate over each date and get the data for the current logged user

so for user 1 it will be:
4/11/2015

```
Customer_ID | Item_ID | Price | Date
----------------------------------------
1           | 15      | 200   | 4/11/2015
1           | 35      | 350   | 4/11/2015
```

and 5/11/2015

```
Customer_ID | Item_ID | Price | Date
----------------------------------------
1           | 15      | 3000  | 5/11/2015
```

what i want is that each iteration i want to get all the user items but only change the value of the price
ex:
4/11/2015

```
Customer_ID | Item_ID | Price | Status
----------------------------------------
1           | 15      | 200   | --
1           | 35      | 350   | --
```

and 5/11/2015

```
Customer_ID | Item_ID | Price | Status
----------------------------------------
1           | 15      | 3000  | UP
1           | 35      | 350   | --
```

what i want is how i can iterate on each time and in every iteration i will show all items that a certain customer has whether the item is in that date or not and if the item does not has a price in this certain date i will show the latest date it has before.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If you want the same items for a particular customer, but change in status, you can write a procedure to get the status according to item, then pass the procedure into select statement in Status column.

Comment: @MorganThrapp i edited my post

Comment: @cassandradied yes that what i want, so i would write a stored which will get the items in a table variable and return it ?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? 2008, 2012, ...?

Comment: @a.tolba yeah, just stored procedure. Or you can use `with` semantics.

Comment: @cassandradied ok i will give it a try and let you know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Customer_ID, ip.Date
FROM ItemPrice AS ip
INNER JOIN Customers AS c ON ip.Item_ID = c.Item_ID
```

in order to get all distinct dates per `Customer_ID`.

**Output:**

```
Customer_ID Date
----------------------
1           2015-04-11 
1           2015-05-11 
3           2015-04-11 
5           2015-04-11
```

You can wrap the above query in a `CTE`, then perform a `LEFT JOIN` to this `CTE` in order to get all possible combinations between `Item_ID` - `Date`:

```
;WITH DatesCTE AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.Customer_ID, ip.Date
  FROM ItemPrice AS ip
  INNER JOIN Customers AS c ON ip.Item_ID = c.Item_ID
)
SELECT Customer_ID, Item_ID, COALESCE(Price, prevPrice) AS Price,
       CASE 
          WHEN prevPrice > Price THEN 'DOWN'
          WHEN prevPrice = Price THEN 'EQUAL'
          WHEN prevPrice < Price THEN 'UP'
          ELSE '---'
       END AS Status
FROM (       
SELECT c.Customer_ID, c.Item_ID, dc.Date, 
       ip.Price,
       LAG(ip.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Customer_ID, c.Item_ID 
                           ORDER BY dc.Date) AS prevPrice       
FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN DatesCTE AS dc ON c.Customer_ID = dc.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN ItemPrice AS ip ON c.Item_ID = ip.Item_ID AND dc.Date = ip.Date ) AS t
ORDER BY Customer_ID, Date
```

The above query uses `LAG` to compare prices between current and previous item. These two values can be used in order to determine `Price` and `Status` fields of the result.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7688/6)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

> select customer_id, item_id, price 
>   from customer c left join history h on c.item_id=h.item_id 
>   where date = '2015-11-04' and customer_id=1

Your question is not clear but `left join` will output data for all users, even if there is no data for the specified date.